# in a rest api design, is there a pattern to get history of object

Tags: rest, api

I have to design a REST API  resource, where it needs to be possible to GET the previous version, and other history versions of an object.

Is there a useful pattern to achieve this?

Would it be a good idea, e.g. to amend
`restapi.baseurl/resourcename/{ID}`     with
`restapi.baseurl/resourcename/{ID}/version/{ID}`

or are there better design options to achieve this?

Comment: There is no default for versioning, your way is a good one

Answer (score 3):

[RFC5829](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5829) defines a number of link relations for usage with versioning.

They include:

- `latest-version`
- `version-history`
- `predecessor-version`
- `successor-version`

You can use these link relationships with the `Link` header, or by choosing a response format for your API that has hypermedia support, such as HAL, JSON:API, Siren, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`restapi.baseurl/resourcename/{ID}/history?from_version=x&to_version=y` is something I prefer using